Way to tell Redis to stop accepting new keys?
I have a strange use case.  I want to tell Redis to temporarily stop accepting new cache entrees.  I want to continue to supply existing keys but not accept new ones. Obviously the right way to do to this would be in the app that is attempting to write to it, but I can't do that.  Is there any clever way to accomplish this in Redis itself?

Would CLIENT PAUSE timeout WRITE work for your purposes? https://redis.io/docs/latest/commands/client-pause/

Yes that works!  I screwed up and undid my upvote and it won't let me restore it.  Thank you so much!
